# Google Apps Scriptで生成したhtmlのGA計測の方法が分からない

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

Google Apps ScriptでhtmlとCSS、JavaScriptを生成し、オリジナルの問い合わせフォームを作り運用しています。
問い合わせフォームはうまく動いていて問題ないのですが、GA計測をどのようにすればいいかわかりません。

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cross-domain

上記ページの記述を参考に設定を試みましたが、うまくいきませんでした。
`script.google.com` のドメインで自動リンクを有効にすることは可能なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

Google Workspace上で動くHTML Viewかと思いますが、利用可能なGoogle Analyticsの測定は限られています。具体的には、Google Workspace Marketplace上での"インストール開始"と"インストール完了"のみであり、UIのクリックなどのイベントを測定する事はできません。

### リファレンス

- https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/use-analytics

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、大変勉強になりました。感謝いたします！